# cakephp How to save data to hasMany through (The Join Model)

Tags: cakephp

I have three tables

Job           Employee     EmployeesJob
---------     --------     ----------------------
id            id           id
name          name         job_id
                           employee_id
                           work_hours

The relationship is hasMany through (The Join Model[EmployeesJob])
What I want to do is when add a new Job, admin can  choose one or many employees, related information will store in EmployeesJob and Job.
in job/admin_add

```
echo $this->Form->input('EmployeesJob.employee_id',array('options'=>$employees, 'label'=>'Employee'));
```

it displays all employees, but admin only can choose one of them, also it doesn't insert a new row in EmployeesJob, My job table has other association tables(HABTM, belong to), so I am not sure saveAssociated($this->request->data) can do all the stuff.

I need help, 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For multiple selection of employees you should write the following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('EmployeesJob.employee_id][',array('options'=>$employees, 'label'=>'Employee', 'multiple' => 'multiple'));
```

To save multiple records, you should write the following in your controller's code:

```
$this->Job->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
```

This link might also help you to achieve the same: [CakePHP saving Foreign Key Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102915/cakephp-saving-foreign-key-issue/12103920#12103920)